# Magento 2: How to split catalog database (split database architecture)?

Tags: magento2, database, catalog

I am trying to use Magento 2.0 split database scalability feature. Below document explains how to split master databases but has no information on splitting slaves.

**How can I set up separate database server for Catalog?**

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/multi-master/multi-master_masterdb.html